# Spring data neo4j: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one with starting with _)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Trying to execute following method on `UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>` but it is throwing an exception

```
@Query(
    "MERGE (user:User {appId:{0}, uid:{1}})" +
    "RETURN user"
)
public User createUserIfNotExists(String appId, String userId);
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one with starting with _) 
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:125)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:42)
```

But changing the query to `"MERGE (user:_User` works and applies the label `_User` to the created node.

**Q1.** Can I tell SDN to attach only `User` as the label and avoid `_User`

**Q2.** If not, then how can I have both `User` and `_User` labels attached to all user nodes. At present only `_User` label is attached

**Edited:**

**Issue1:**

With my previous SDN version (i.e. `3.0.0.RELEASE`), suddenly query `user:User:_User` started working but then failing for `Song` repository for the similar query `song:Song:_Song` but works for `song:_Song` or `song:Song`

**Issue2:**

The moment I update my SDN or Neo4j version, I get strange exceptions and that's why I didn't update my versions of SDN and Neo4j.

Just now I updated my SDN to version `3.1.1` and kept the neo4j version same (i.e. `2.0.1`) and the code is also the same but then I got the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.<init>(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:50)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:396)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
```

at line `ApplicationContext appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);`

Answer (score 3):

> It needs the labels with the underscore to identify the one which
>   actually belongs to this class (in the inheritance hierarchy).
>
> Michael

Use:

```
MERGE (user:User:_User {appId:{0}, uid:{1}})
RETURN user
```

or

```
MERGE (user:User {appId:{0}, uid:{1}})
ON CREATE SET user:_User
RETURN user
```

Comment: Which version of SDN/neo4j are you using? I'm using SDN 3.1.1 and Neo4j 2.1.2 and it is working fine.

Comment: <springDataNeo4jVersion>3.0.0.RELEASE</springDataNeo4jVersion>, <neo4jVersion>2.0.1</neo4jVersion>

Comment: @MichaelHunger I updated my SDN version to 3.1.1 and got into another issue... I have mentioned the issues in my question (edited)

Comment: Try with updating neo4j to 2.1.2.

Comment: @YatendraGoel upgrade to spring 3.2.9.RELEASE as that is version SDN uses.